# suspicious cast there is no type in the solution which is inherited from--> why/somehow it is working

Tags: c#, casting, mocking, com, autodesk-inventor

i am currently working on an AddIn for Inventor(3d Modeling Software). When you are using the api there are two different kind of documents

- AssemblyDocument
- PartDocument

the api provides me a method which returns the selected document.

```
   PartDocument part = ((PartDocument)application.ActiveDocument);
```

during runtime this cast works. The compiler tells me that this is a suspicious cast, because the 'PartDocument' does not implements the type the 'application.ActiveDocument' returns.

```
 [TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FDispatchable)]
  [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
  [Guid("xxxxxx")]
  [DefaultMember("Type")]
  [ComImport]
  public interface PartDocument
  {
....
```

```
 [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
  [TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FDispatchable)]
  [Guid("xxxxx")]
  [DefaultMember("Type")]
  [ComImport]
  public interface Application
  {...

    [DispId(50331905)]
    _Document ActiveDocument { [DispId(50331905), MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)] [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] get; }
```

```
[Guid("xxxxxx")]
  [CoClass(typeof (_DocumentClass))]
  [ComImport]
  public interface _Document : Document, _VbaImplementationEvents_Event
  {
  }
```

So why is this working ? Can someone explain this this to me ?

And how can i test this ?

```
var documentMock =new Mock<PartDocument>();
var applicationMock = new Mock<Application>();
applicationMock.Setup(x => x.ActiveDocument).Returns(documentMock.Object);
```

The compiler tells me that he cannot cast from 'PartDocument' to '_Document' --> this is true, so why is it working during runtime ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because it is a COM type. For COM type casting, the interop handler will automatically call [`IUnknown.QueryInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(refiid_void)) on the COM object (every COM object implements IUnknown) to find out if it supports `PartDocument` interface, and get the location of the relevant VTable. This is entirely disconnected from the .NET type specification, and, theoretically, could return a different result each time it was called.